# Vuejs: Cannot resolve file 'particles.js'

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

When I import particles.js, I get `Cannot resolve file 'particles.js` error. particle js is installed to my project using `npm i particles.js`, and it is added to my dependency folder and package-lock folder.

```
import {Component, Prop, Vue} from 'vue-property-decorator';
import ParticleJS from 'particles.js'

@Component
export default class ParticlesJS extends Vue {
name:'particlesJS'
    mounted(){

    console.log('mounted');

}

    data(){
    return{

        user:{ firstName:'John', lastName:'Doe'},

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Have you checked that the package exists in the node_modules folder?

Comment: `particles.js` has not been designed as a JS module, so you can't `import` it. I suggest you use [vue-particles](https://vue-particles.netlify.com/) instead as it's already done all the work required

Comment: See https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/issues/192. There's a PR to make it export a UMD here too ~ https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/pull/198

Comment: @ba_ul yes, it is in the node_modules folder

Comment: @Phil's link should take you to the solution. Instead of importing here, either do `require` when `mounted` or use vue-particles.